# Does plastic expand at colder temperatures?

Tags: plastic

After placing a dry solid block of nonporous plastic material in the freezer for a while, I was surprised to find out when I retrieved it that it had expanded globally by a few inches. Which type of plastic must this be and do plastics expand at colder temperatures?

Comment: Is the plastic material a solid block or a structure? Is it porous? What else was present? Was it wet?

Comment: a few INCHES???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materials with a negative thermal expansion (NTE) coefficient will increase in size as they are cooled down. Not all plastics have a NTE, but it is not a property seen only in one specific type of plastic. I don't think the plastic can be identified only knowing that it has a NTE.